# Java + Jersey + Gradle - java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found

Tags: java, sql, gradle, jersey

Having trouble getting SQL working in a Java WebApp that I'm working on.  It seems to be an issue with jersey not loading my sql driver.

Getting a **java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:h2:testDbName** when I call my endpoint.

Note that:

1. the connection string is valid and works when not being run in the
   WebContainer.
2. gradle script is configured to correctly place sqldriver (h2 in this
   case) in lib directory

I've simplified the code to the following:

TestResource.java

```
@Path("/user")
public class TestResource {

    @POST
    @Path("/add")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public Response createForm(@FormParam("name") String name) throws Exception{

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:testDbName");
        connection.close();

        return Response.status(SC_ACCEPTED).build();
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'war'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile "javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:1.1.1"
    compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-bundle:1.19'

    compile 'com.h2database:h2:1.3.175'
}
```

webapp.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>testPackage</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Try explicitly loading the driver and see what happens `Class.forName("org.h2.Driver")`

Comment: Yeah, that fixed it -- I placed  static{
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.h2.Driver())
    } into my code .. Seems very smelly though

Comment: @vicjugador why smelly? This is how it works in java, you need to load the driver.

Comment: @peeskillet - Seems off that I don't normally have to do this, but with Tomcat I have to.

Comment: @Opal I might be mistaken, but I think starting from Java 8 you don't need to load it, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/overview/index.html). Might be a Java version problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per peeskillet, explicitly loading the driver fixed the problem.

```
@Path("/user")
public class TestResource {

    static{ DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.h2.Driver()) } 

    @POST
    @Path("/add")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public Response createForm(@FormParam("name") String name) throws Exception{

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:testDbName");
        connection.close();

        return Response.status(SC_ACCEPTED).build();
    }
}
```